# Powershell - Results not combined

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell command that lists usernames and displays within a OU. When I run the following

```
$cs = get-aduser @ADUserParams | select-object @SelectParams
write-host $cs.DisplayName "," $cs.SAMAccountname
```

The results are not in the expected format:

```
Bob Leyland Sam Leyland , bob.leyland sam.leyland
```

I have tried to pass this through a loop but receive the same line twice. Out of my depth here.

I would like

```
Bob Leyland,bob.leyland
Sam Leyland,sam.leyland
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the command to `ForEach-Object` or `%` for its shorthand alias:

```
$cs = get-aduser @ADUserParams | select-object @SelectParams | % { write-host "$($_.DisplayName) , $($_.SAMAccountname)" }
```